# WCF Connection becomes faulted for no reason

Tags: wcf

Or perhaps it has a reason it just does not tell me about.

This is what I am doing to connect my client:

```
try
            {
                callback = new Callback();
                //my callback implementation
                callback.send += new Callback.gotPacket(callback_send);
                //Event so the client gets informed when the callback function is
                //triggerd.
                InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(callback);
                client = new ServiceReference1.WcfInfoHostClient(context);
                client.connect();
                //This is always working as long as the server is running.
                statuslabel.Content = "Conected";
                //writing somthing to the GUI
                filterentries = client.getFilter();
                //this should return a datatable object but it
                //always fails due to a ConnectionFaultedException
                filtergrid.ItemsSource = filterentries.DefaultView;
                //[...]
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                statuslabel.Content = ex.Message;
            }
```

How can the connection become faulted all of a sudden? I added the getFilter Function to the Service interface, to the Service implentation. I refreshed the WCF service DLL in the window service hosting it and I have refreshed all ServiceReferences in all concerning projects. 
I dont see what is goning on here....

Comment: Perhaps the connection is timing out? Did you enable the ServiceModel logging to see what is happening?

Comment: The connection is timing out in about 100 miliseconds? Besides the Callback is getting informed by the service with no problem when I remove the client.getFilter() line, so this would not be my guess. The ServiceModel logging requires several steps which I could not comprehend so far and involves hand changes to that highly fragile app.conf xml file, so I was not brave enough to do that until now.

Comment: what does the GetFilter() do? does it use any un-serializable objects?

Comment: I think the simple way to avoid the timeout is to increase it and implement some kind of long pooling. 100ms looks like the timeout from HTTP.SYS underlying channel.

Comment: @Dhawalk: getFilter does: 'return new DataTable()'

Comment: @Dhawalk Thanks for giving the hint. The problem was the empty table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments. The problem is that
a) WCF cant use empty DataTables 
b) You have to give the DataTable a name.

I changed my implementation to this:

```
public DataTable getFilter()
    {
        DataTable result = new DataTable("fascinatingName");
        result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("I", typeof(String)));
        result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("am", typeof(String)));
        result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("a", typeof(String)));
        result.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Test", typeof(String)));
        return result;

    }
```

Now the communication is working without problems. Still WCF makes me cry.

Have a fantastic weekend everyone....